# Convert web.config file to .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I have a web.config file that I have tried converting to .htaccess and it's not working as intended. I'd love some help figuring out where I went wrong.

web.config

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to https">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="Blocker" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/version_" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/404/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="API Director">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/api/v1/" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/controller.php" />
            </rule>

            <rule name="HoverCart App" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <!--<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)(quiverstest.)" />-->
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/newrelic/" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="\app\{R:0}" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule (.*)    https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/version_
RewriteRule (.*)    https://www.example.com/404/

RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/api/v1/
RewriteRule (.*)    /controller.php

RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/newrelic/
RewriteRule .*    \app\$0
```

specifically /api/v1 isn't working. Im getting a 404 when its trying to pull in https://localhost/api/v1/app/

to be honest I dont know much about either web.config or .htaccess, I'm trying to set up something on a mac that was initially made for windows machines.

**EDIT**

the most important rule that I need to rewrite is this one

```
<rule name="API Director">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
     <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/api/v1/" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/controller.php" />
 </rule>
```

this is the error that I get

```
The requested URL /api/v1/app/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*)    https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}` I'm kinda surprised that doesn't result in a terminal loop tbh - unless http and https have different docroots (and therefore .htaccess rules).

Comment: hmm like I said, I really have 0 experience with either web.config and .htaccess so Im not too sure:P but, It doesnt result in a terminal loop. and I don't think they have different docRoots either

Comment: Enable the rewritelog. All those `RewriteCond %PATH_INFO` are redundant. Move the actual regex in place of the RewriteRule `(.*)` for starters.

Comment: what would that look like? @mario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a rather crude autotranslation you got there.

- Regex rules should rarely go into RewriteConds:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} ^/api/v1/
  RewriteRule (.*)    /controller.php
  ```

  Should each be just:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^api/v1/    /controller.php
  ```

  > The leading `/` should be omitted (from any `^/…`).
- Environment references need `%` in Apache context:

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*)    https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
                              ↑           ↑
  ```

  This one in particular needs a RewriteCond to only match for http:// requests.
- Pretty sure these should be forward slashes:

  ```
  RewriteRule .*    \app\$0
                    ↑   ↑
  ```
- Keep the comments from the original web.config

Comment: Thank you! this brought me much closer I do however still get this error `The requested URL /api/v1/app/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: [How to debug Apache mod\_rewrite](//stackoverflow.com/q/9632852)